# How to uninstall (or delete) one of 2 ubuntu 12.4 LTS in my computer

Tags: uninstall

I have 2 ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my computer. Both of them have the same name. I want to uninstall one that is in safe mode. What's the best way to achieve the purpose? Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

if you not use wubi, use dual boot? This will help you! :D there http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUgf84bdYvg

Comment: I have a DVD with ubuntu via download. I installed it a second time, because the first didn't run. I think, but I'm not sure, that after using the application tasksel, the graphic interface stopped functioning. After installing a second Linux, the 2 have the same name, I could recover some files and now I need it no more, so I want uninstall it. But I don't know how. That's the question.